# Knee stiffness and soreness

Tags: crossfit

I do Crossfit WOD's 5 times a week. After running one day carrying two 20 lb med balls, my right knee was very stiff the next day. It's been about 3 weeks and the stiffness has not decreased. I am still working out but trying to avoid squats and I haven't run. I've been icing my knee, elevating it when I can and wearing an ace bandage. I'm not sure what to do next. I'm a 45 yr old female in good shape.

Comment: Seek medical attention.

Comment: Does it hurt when you go up or down stairs?  Are there any tender areas?  Do any activities make it feel better or worse?  And I guess you know by now... don't run while carrying weights.